# Can I list objects sorted by date?

Tags: r

This would be very useful to me. Can I sort the output of `ls()` by date (last modified or something similar)?

**Context:** I have a very messy workspace full of various `data.frames`, `variables` and `plots`. I need to find a `data.frame` and I cannot remember what I called it, only that I was working on it recently. Hence `ls()` sorted by date modified would help me work out what I called it.

**To clarify:** This is not a question about using `history()`. I use history frequently and often save it when I think it might be required. In this case, history does not cover the period required, so I cannot find the `data.frame` using `history()`.

**Additional:** Aside from the stated task of finding a recently created `data.frame`, it would be very useful, in general, to be able to sort `ls()` according to date. I have well over 100 objects in the workspace that I have been working on for over 2 years (searching 2 years of `history` does not sound fun either). If it were possible to sort these objects into a chronological order then I would have some idea of which were newer (and possibly edited) and which were older (and perhaps original).

I have attempted to improve my workflow by slowly moving individual objects into smaller, related workspaces. But this process will take time, and is essentially pointless (as I am nearing the end of data analysis anyway).

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit? Why would you like to do this? What would you do with the result?

Comment: Could `history()` be useful for you??

Comment: No. History doesn't help. Unfortunately. BTW history was my first port of call. I do even have a saved history. Doesn't cover the period I am interested in.

Comment: Umm, this is a strange problem. Using an IDE like RStudio should prevent it.

Comment: I actually found it strange that I couldn't do it immediately (hence asking a SO question). As for using RStudio, I have tried it out, but I find working in the terminal better for me. Obviously I should have kept better records.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining that someone would find "working in the terminal better" than using an IDE. I've started using R with Rgui and just rerunning code was often a major task. I've once recommended Rstudio to a beginner and later found out he didn't know to open a new Rscript, which contradicted the whole idea of using an IDE. This is the only scenario, where I would understand why the advantage is not obvious.

Comment: I have used Rstudio and Rcmdr. I did use Rstudio for a bit, and went back to the terminal. I found RStudio to be a bit buggy at that time. I am a linux user and it is not unknown for me to ssh into various machines to run R. But that's just me...

Comment: Do you know _anything_ about the `data.frame` you're looking for other than that you used it "recently" (but not that recently)?  Does it have more/less rows/columns than other data.frames?  Different rownames/colnames?  Does it have smaller/larger values on average? Do you know what one of the values is?  Any other different attributes?  Did you use it to create a model (i.e. can you look at the data to in the model object and then find a `data.frame` that matches?).  Did you plot it with something that stores the plot object (or did you store a plot object)?

Comment: Would this be a good time and place to suggest an introduction to 6-S Process Flow?  :-)

Comment: IMHO, instead of saving a workspace, you should save the objects you need with `save` or `saveRDS`.  Those files will then have a time associated with them.  Also, always save the code you used to create those objects so that you can recreate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you should use the `history`function to find its name through the latest commands you have run.

By default, `history` will show the last 25 lines of code, but you can request more by doing:

```
history(max.show = 100)
```

There is also a hard limit on the number of lines you can show. It is equal to the value of the environment variable `R_HISTSIZE` whose default is 512. But as the documentation says:

> There is no limit on the number of lines of history retained during a session [...]

so you can do:

```
Sys.setenv("R_HISTSIZE" = 10000)
history(max.show = 10000)
```

and you should be able to see all your history since you started your session (assuming you ran less than 10000 lines of code.)

Comment: If one forgets how many lines of history are saved, they can get everything available through `history(max.show = Inf)`.

Answer (score 4):

Something you might try is automating the logging of modifications to variables of interest using the `makeActiveBinding` function. You could then use the log to sort the output of `ls()` by modification time.

One caveat is that, using this method, tracking has to be set up before the variable is first used.

```
.change.log <- list()
track <- function(variable) {
    makeActiveBinding(variable,
        function(v) 
            if (! missing(v)) 
            .change.log[[variable]] <<- c(.change.log[[variable]], 
                                           as.list(Sys.time())),
        .GlobalEnv)
}

track('x')
x <- 1
.change.log
x <- 2
.change.log
```

Each time `x` is modified, the anonymous function supplied to `makeActiveBinding` gets called with `v` equal to the new value. This function also gets called when `x` is referenced, but with nothing supplied to `v` in this case, hence the conditional with `missing(v)`---we only want to update the log when the value changes.

---

#### EDIT

After further consideration, a better alternative to `makeActiveBinding` would be to install a modification logger via the function `addTaskCallback`. The code below creates an automated logger that records timestamps by variable name every time the `<-` operator is used at the top level.

```
# define a log maker function. This returns a new logger function
# bound with a fresh log.
mk.log <- function() {
    log <- list()
    # handler functions have to have these four args, but we only use the first.
    function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
        if (class(expr) == '<-') {
            # convert the assignment call to a list, so the 
            # variable name can be extracted
            call.list <- as.list(expr)
            # extract the name of the variable being affected, and 
            # convert it to character, so we can use it as a list name
            variable <- as.character(call.list[[2]])
            # append a timestamp to the log for this variable
            log[[variable]] <<- c(log[[variable]], list(Sys.time()))
        }
        # callback handlers need to return a bool
        return(TRUE)
    }
}

# assign the handler to .log, and install it.
addTaskCallback(.log <- mk.log(), name='log')

x <- 5
x <- 10
y <- 4

# read the log
environment(.log)$log

# $x
# $x[[1]]
# [1] "2013-01-25 10:24:26.581 EST"
# 
# $x[[2]]
# [1] "2013-01-25 10:24:26.585 EST"
# 
# 
# $y
# $y[[1]]
# [1] "2013-01-25 10:24:26.589 EST"
```

Comment: Is "v" supposed to be "variable" (in `function(v)` )?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No, `v` will be the new value every time the variable named by the string in `variable` gets changed, meaning you could set this up to track not only modification time, but also modification value.

Answer (score 3):

Well, with a little creative hacking, you could write your own methods for your variables.
E.g.:

```
datedmatrix<-function(data,nrow,ncol,...) {
    output <- matrix(data, nrow=nrow,ncol=ncol,...)
    attr(output,'create') <- date()
    return(output)
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't help after the fact, but it certainly raises the question as to why objects don't have a date associated with them.

Comment: @RSoul, I don't think the ability to add an attribute raises the question as to why all imaginable attributes aren't added by default...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ls.str(mode="list")`.

Example output:

```
b : 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ test: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
c : 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: num 1
```

I don't think the creation time is stored with any R objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea, we create a log and all actions using `:=` will be stored there :

```
`:=` <- function(e1,e2){
  log <- data.frame(
    var = paste(collapse="\n",deparse(substitute(e1))),
    call=  paste(collapse="\n",deparse(substitute(e2))),
    time = Sys.time()
  )
  if(exists(".log",envir = .GlobalEnv)){
    assign(".log", 
           rbind(get(".log", envir = .GlobalEnv), log), 
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } else {
    assign(".log", log, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }  
  eval.parent(do.call(
    substitute, list(match.call(), list(`:=` = quote(.Primitive("<-"))))))
}

x := 1
x := x+2
x
# [1] 3
.log
#   var  call                time
# 1   x     1 2019-02-26 12:17:24
# 2   x x + 2 2019-02-26 12:17:25
```

With a few tweaks we could also log every assignment made with `<-` in the global environment, but it will slow down R.

```
`<-` <- function(e1,e2){
  if(identical(parent.frame(), .GlobalEnv)){
    log <- data.frame(
      var = paste(collapse="\n",deparse(substitute(e1))),
      call=  paste(collapse="\n",deparse(substitute(e2))),
      time = Sys.time()
    )
    if(exists(".log",envir = .GlobalEnv)){
      assign(".log", 
             rbind(get(".log", envir = .GlobalEnv), log), 
             envir = .GlobalEnv)
    } else {
      assign(".log", log, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }    
  } 

  eval.parent(do.call(substitute, list(
    match.call(), list(`<-` = quote(.Primitive("<-"))))))
}

rm(.log)
var <- 1
var <- var +1
var
fun <- function(x) {y <- x+1; y}
var2 <- fun(var)
var
# [1] 2
var2
# [1] 3
.log
#    var                                    call                time
# 1  var                                       1 2019-02-26 12:52:13
# 2  var                                 var + 1 2019-02-26 12:52:13
# 3  fun function(x) {\n    y <- x + 1\n    y\n} 2019-02-26 12:52:14
# 4 var2                                fun(var) 2019-02-26 12:52:14
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct answer, but personally I use RStudio.

Rstudio has a tab history (which mostly uses history R command) with a very good search options.

Here I search in my history for the word source.
[image]

To get more details I can go to the context of each line in this history. For example here the details of the first line.
[image]